# Detecting if application is installed from Huawei AppGallery

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, android-package-managers, huawei-developers, appgallery

I would like to detect the app installation source.

We can use two approaches on Android to detect the installation source: `PackageManager#getInstallerPackageName(String)` or `PackageManager#getInstallSourceInfo(String)`. Both of those calls will return a package name of the installer application. For example:

- Amazon Appstore: `com.amazon.venezia`
- Google Play: `com.android.vending`

**My question is**, what does this method returns for applications installed from Huawei AppGallery?

Answer (score 5):

You can check "com.huawei.appmarket" using the same method.